# Problem with obtaining consent with ump / admob / funding choices

Tags: java, android, gdprconsentform

Following this guide https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start I tried to add everything to my app.

What I did:

- link funding choices to admob
- added ump to build.gradle
- added the app ID to android manifest
- set up a dialog for the app in admob and activated it for the app

Then I added this code to my app

```
ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters
                .Builder()
                .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
                .build();

        consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this);
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
                this,
                params,
                new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdateSuccess() {
                        // The consent information state was updated.
                        // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
                        if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable()) {
                            loadForm();
                        }
                        else {

                        Context context = getApplicationContext();

                        CharSequence toastText = "No Form Available";

                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, toastText, duration);
                        toast.show();
                        }

                        
                    }

                },
                new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError formError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                        
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();

                        CharSequence toastText = "Error";

                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, toastText, duration);
                        toast.show();

                    }
                });
```

and

```
public void loadForm() {
        UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
                this,
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadSuccess(ConsentForm consentForm) {
                        MainActivity.this.consentForm = consentForm;
                        if(consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                            consentForm.show(
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    new ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onConsentFormDismissed(@Nullable FormError formError) {
                                            // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                                            loadForm();
                                        }
                                    });

                        }
                    }
                },
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadFailure(FormError formError) {
                        // Handle the error
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

However, I always end up getting the toast "Error" landing in onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError formError) independet from testing on my mobile phone or in the virtual device (I am in europe btw).

Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Celdri

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue and I solved it just by configuring properly my adMob account.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you tell me what has been the problem with your adMob account. I asked google support and they couldn't help me either.